# Wordpress - multiple pages site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to Wordpress and using the html5blank theme for the first time. I've built the home page with all the code on the page.php file. I have a host of other pages I need to create which I've started doing on the wp-admin dashboard but what I can't seem to figure out is where I put the code for each page?
Do I create individual text files for each - product.php / about.php etc ? How do all the different paths link up on the site?

I'm sure this is a really straightforward thing for an experienced WP developer. Any help appreciated.

Comment: WP is fairly well documented, Google is a good search tool. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: Google "wordpress template hierarchy"

Comment: @WheatBeak Thanks, do you recommend any plugins for importing multiple html pages? I've seen html import 2 - is that the main one to use?

Comment: Don't know, sorry.  I avoid plugins like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called aboutus.php and add this at the top.

```
<?
/*
Template Name: AboutUs
*/
?>
```

This wil make the template show up on the page atributes in wp, where you can select it as the template for your page. This is very basic... you can read up on template files here... https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/